# Python Logging Multiple Errors on Single Line

Tags: python, logging, error-handling

I'm trying to log some expected errors.

Initially, I wrote my script like:

```
   except (BadZipFile, MemoryError) as e:
       logger.error(f'No: {n} - {filename} = {e}')
```

But I noticed in the logger, only the `BadZipFile` error message seemed to make it. The `MemoryError` logs seemed to be blank after the `=` sign

I thought maybe the `e` was only storing the `BadZipFile` error message since it comes first, so I tried making a tuple:

```
   except (BadZipFile, MemoryError) as (eb, em):
       logger.error(f'No: {n} - {filename} = {eb, em}')
```

but of course the  syntax is wrong. So what's going wrong with my code initially? Why is the `MemoryError` log not storing?

Comment: I've noticed the same thing.  The string representation of a MemoryError is a blank space.  I suppose the reason is that if the system is running out of memory, it doesn't have any space to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with how you’re handling that error. It just means the message of a memory error is blank. Do you have any indication that it should be otherwise?

Comment: No reason to think otherwise, just wasn't aware. Good to know. I can just add a condition that if e is blank, to fill it with the appropriate text.

Answer (score 0):

Execution of program will be stopped when it occurs an exception and move to the except block. So when an exception occurred it is not possible to get another in the same `try` block. So will always receives one log of exception.

let me explain it with a bit of code, consider we have two types of errors, `IndexError` and `ZeroDivisionError`

Case1:

```
>>> l = []
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 0
>>> try:
...     x = l[0]
...     y = a/b
... except (IndexError, ZeroDivisionError) as e:
...     print(e)
...
list index out of range
```

Case2:

```
>>> try:
...     x = a/b
...     y = l[0]
... except (IndexError, ZeroDivisionError) as e:
...     print(e)
...
division by zero
```

Case3:

```
>>> try:
...     x = l[0]/b
... except (IndexError, ZeroDivisionError) as e:
...     print(e)
...
list index out of range
>>>
```

Case1, IndexError is raised first, so except bock is called with IndexError

Case2, ZeroDivisionError raised first, so except block is called with ZeroDivisionError

Case3, even though both exceptions are in single line line of execution happens from indexing so IndexError is raised.

EDIT:

In your case `BadZipFile` exception raised first, so your except block `except (BadZipFile, MemoryError) as e:` is called with `BadZipFile` exception. That's why your output is empty for `MemoryError`.

Even if `MemoryError` raised first with empty arguments then it will log nothing.

```
>>> try:
...     raise MemoryError("This is memory error")
... except MemoryError as e:
...     print(e)
...
This is memory error
>>> try:
...     raise MemoryError()
... except MemoryError as e:
...     print(e)
...

>>>
```

Comment: Maybe you could add a note that MemoryError message is blank to this as well so I can mark this as a comprehensive solution. Thanks for writing this up.

Comment: This is really close to being fully correct now. As it turns out MemoryError just returns an empty space. That's why my output is empty whenever it encounters a MemoryError. Even without the BadZipFile error being there or not? Can you update your edit at the bottom so I can reward the solution as correct?

Answer (score 0):

Whichever exception occurs first will get caught in except block. So, I think in your case 1st exception raising is BadZipFile. refer to @LMKR examples.

try to raise an exception explicitly to check whether it's working or not...

```
>>> try:
...     if True:
...         raise MemoryError("MemoryError occured")
... except (BadZipFile, MemoryError) as e:
...     print(e)
```